# Embedding into Adjunction space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

Let $X\cup_f Y$ be an adjunction space and $q:X\coprod Y\rightarrow X\cup_f Y$ be the associated quotient map. Let $A\subseteq Y$ be closed and $f:A\rightarrow X$ be a continuous map (this is called the attaching map).
Note that there exists a canonical injection $\sigma$ from $X$ to the disjoint union

Note, $X \cup_f Y$ is the quotient space obtained by the relation $a\sim f(a)$ for all $a\in A$.

Problem:
The restriction of $q$ to $X$ is a topological embedding, whose image set $q(X)$ is a closed subset of $X\cup_f Y$.

My attempt: Clearly, $q|_X$ is continuous. I was able to show injectivity in a [different post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555445/adjunction-space-quotient-properties). So, in this post, I will that $q|_X$ is a closed map.

Let $B$ be a closed subset of $X\coprod Y$. Then I must show that 
$q|_X(B)=q(B)$ is closed in the quotient space, equivalently, $q^{-1}(q(B))$ is closed in $X\coprod Y$.

I was able to show that

$\sigma_0^{-1}(q^{-1}(q(B)) = \sigma_0^{-1}(B)$ and that

$\sigma_1^{-1}(q^{-1}(q(B))=f^{-1}(\sigma_0^{-1}(B))$

and so $q^{-1}(q(B))$ is closed in the disjoint union.

Since $X$ is closed in the disjoint union, it follows that $q(X)$ is closed in the quotient space.

Is this correct? (please answer this)

Another question I have is, the continuous map, $f:A\rightarrow X$ (forgetting the identification), is still the map, $f:A\rightarrow X$, right?

Comment: You might consider changing your title, since it's very non-descriptive and almost identical to your other recent question. Maybe something like "Why is $X \hookrightarrow X\cup_f Y$ a topological embedding?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if $x \in X$ there is at most one $a \in A \subseteq Y$ such that $f(a)=x$ so that $a \sim x$ and $q(a)=q(x)$. No further identifications are made that concern $x$. That's why $q\restriction_X$ is injective (In my courses $f$ always went from $A$ (subset of $X$) to $Y$, which makes this confusing for me).

Indeed to see $q'=q\restriction_X: X \to X\cup_f Y$ is closed, we check that $q'[X]=q[X]$ is closed in $X\cup_f Y$ and this is equivalent to $q^{-1}[q[X]] \subseteq X \coprod Y$ being closed and by the final topology definition this in turn is equivalent to $\sigma_X^{-1}[q^{-1}[q[X]]]] \subseteq X$ being closed (but this is just $X$ so that's OK) and $\sigma_Y^{-1}[q^{-1}[q[X]]]$ being closed in $Y$, but this set equals $A$ which is closed in $Y$ (you don't mention it, but this is usually implicit if you say "adjunction space". So $q'[X]$ is closed in $X \cup_f Y$.

For closed $B$ of $X$ we see that $\sigma_X^{-1}[q^{-1}[q'[B]]] = B$, so closed in  $X$ and $\sigma_Y^{-1}[q^{-1}[q'[B]]] = f^{-1}[B]$ which is closed in $A$ so closed in $Y$ under the (as said common) assumption that $A$ is closed in $Y$. In total one concludes that $q$ is a closed embedding of $X$ into $X \cup_f Y$.

So your approach is good, but again be careful in your identifications. One $X$ is not the same as the other, just equivalent under the $\sigma_X$.

It's quite similar to check that $q$ on $Y \setminus A$ also is an embedding, but an open one, if $A$ is closed in $Y$.

And finally, on $q[A]$ we can also define a version of $f$: $$\tilde{f}: q[A] \to X: \tilde{f}(q(a))=f(a)$$ which is also well-defined and continuous. I'm not sure if that is what you mean by the last sentence? Or do you mean $f': \sigma_Y[A] \subseteq X \coprod Y \to X$ defined by $f'(\sigma_Y(a))=f(a)$, which is also possible?

Comment: just to be clear, when I "forgot" the identifications above in my attempt, have I forgotten them correctly?

Comment: Oh, yeah, your solution indicated that I did. Thank you!

Comment: In my last sentence, I meant how is the attaching map originally defined (without identification?). $f: A\times$ $ \{$ 1 $\}$ $\rightarrow$ $X \times \{$0 $\}$  is not what the author had in mind, right?

Comment: @topologicalmagician No just $f: A \to X$, but on $X \cup_f Y$ you can sort of define it too if you identify some sets.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats what I thought. If I may ask... I felt like this was this case, but I wasn't sure how to completely reason that is the case. Is there a particular reason why its not supposed to be the other way?