# Embedding into adjunction space without closedness assumption

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $A$ be a subspace of a space $Y$, and let $f:A\to X$ be a continuous map. Then we can form the adjunction space $X\cup_f Y$. It is well-known that the natural map $X\to X\cup_f Y$ is a (closed) embedding (for example, [Embedding into Adjunction space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555978/embedding-into-adjunction-space)), if $A$ is closed in $Y$.

My question is, Is the map $X\to X\cup_f Y$ an (not necessarily closed) embedding even if $A$ is not closed in $Y$? This seems true because the quotient map $X\cup Y\to X\cup_f Y$ doesn't identify any two distinct points in $X$. But I can't prove that this is indeed true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q:X\sqcup Y\to X\cup_f Y$ be the quotient map and let $C\subseteq X$ be any closed subset.  Note that since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $A$, so there is a closed subset $D\subseteq Y$ such that $D\cap A=f^{-1}(C)$.  Then $C\sqcup D\subseteq X\sqcup Y$ is a closed subset.  Note moreover that $C\sqcup D$ is saturated with respect to the quotient map $q$ because $D\cap A=f^{-1}(C)$.  Thus $q(C\sqcup D)$ is closed in $X\cup_f Y$, and its intersection with the copy of $X$ in $X\cup_f Y$ is just $C$.  Thus $C$ is closed in the subspace topology on this copy of $X$.  Since $C$ was an arbitrary closed subset of $X$, this proves the map $X\to X\cup_f Y$ is an embedding.

Comment: Why is $C \sqcup D$ equal to $q^{-1}(q(C \sqcup D))$? Could you add some detail for this?

Comment: If $q(x)=q(y)$ then $x$ and $y$ are related by a finite number of steps, where in each step you either replace an element $a\in A$ with $f(a)$ or replace an element of $X$ with one of its preimages under $f$.  Points in $C$ have all their preimages under $f$ contained in $D$, and points in $D\cap A$ have all their images under $f$ contained in $C$.  So if you start with a point of $C\sqcup D$, each step can only take you to another point of $C\sqcup D$.